# Serialize ASCIIEncoding

Tags: c#, сериализация

Работаю сейчас с AR (Active Reports), есть у них классы `HTMLExport`, `PdfExport`, `TextExport`. Так вот в текст экспорт есть public свойство `Encoding Encoding`, которое содержит кодировки. При сериализации этого объекта падает exception который описал выше.

Решил немного поэкспериментировать и попробовать сериализовать, например, объект типа `ASCIIEncoding` и снова получаю ошибку

> The type System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

Хотя класс с атрибутом `Serializable`. Код примера ниже:

```
class Program
{
    static readonly XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (ASCIIEncoding));

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // СЕРИАЛИЗАЦИЯ.

        using (var stream = new FileStream("Serialization.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
        {
            // Сохраняем объект в XML-файле на диске(СЕРИАЛИЗАЦИЯ).
            try
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, new ASCIIEncoding());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Дайте воспроизводящий пример. Как мы по одному тексту ошибки догадаемся, что в вашем объекте не так?

Comment: То есть вы сериализуете не ваш объект, а чужой?

Comment: Все верно. В примере я пытаюсь сериализовать объект из библиотеки System.Text  ASCIIEncoding. Но если смотреть под рефлектором он имеет атрибут Serializable, что говорит нам что мы можем его сериализовать. Хотя при сериализации вылетает ошибка. И я не могу понять что не так и как можно выкрутиться из данной ситуации.

Comment: Хм. Ну, атрибут `Serializable` означает, что класс умеет делать бинарную сериализацию, но не то, что он умеет делать XML-сериализацию. И вы никак не можете это контролировать. Сериализуйте лучше вместо него собственный объект.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже сказано в комментариях, атрибут `Serializable` не имеет отношения к xml-сериализации, он нужен для `BinaryFormatter`а.

Класс `Encoding` напрямую нельзя сериализовать в xml. Поэтому, как предложил VladD, нужно вместо него сериализовать собственный объект. Например, так:

```
public class Test
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Encoding Encoding { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Encoding")]
    public string EncodingValue
    {
        get => Encoding.EncodingName;
        set => Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(value);
    }
}
```

Свойство `Encoding` помечаем атрибутом `XmlIgnore` - в результате сериализатор не будет обращать на него внимания. А вместо него в будет (де)сериализоваться его строковое значение.

Недостаток этого способа в том, что теперь в нашем классе присутствует лишнее свойство `EncodingValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Идею уловил. Буду думать. Хотя ситуация у меня немного сложнее. Есть класс TextExport. Он от стороннего разработчика и sealed. Этот класс содержит свойство Encoded которое не хотело сериализоваться, когда использовал XmlSerializer. Пока ищу решение временно отключил сериализацию этого свойства.

```
public static string Serialize(object exportObject)
    {
        if (exportObject == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("exportObject cannot be null.");
        try
        {
            var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
            var attrs = new XmlAttributes { XmlIgnore = true };
            overrides.Add(typeof(Component), "Site", attrs);

            attrs = new XmlAttributes { XmlIgnore = true };
            overrides.Add(typeof(TextExport), "Encoding", attrs);

            var temp = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), overrides);
            var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            temp.Serialize(stringWriter, exportObject);
            string serializedXml = stringWriter.ToString();
            stringWriter.Dispose();
            return serializedXml;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not serialize the object.", ex);
        }
    }
```